# Is it safe to download code from GitHub?

Tags: github

I'm fairly new when it comes to using GitHub, so I'm a bit skeptical when it comes to downloading repos and running them on my machine. I am looking at a key logger right now, for personal use (fun) and not to do anything malicious.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I would just like to know how people that are experienced with GitHub filter safe repos from others that may be malicious. I don't want to expose my system to any vulnerabilities.

Comment: The answer to that is to read and understand all code before you run it. But this has nothing to do with github per se.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with github when transmitting code to and from their server to end-user, or getting modified in the middle without the repo-owner's knowledge (pretty rare and almost impossible with git, maybe)?

Comment: I can think of a number of ways in which a person could be concerned with safety when downloading from a site like Github. Is Github's infrastructure secure so that an attacker could not introduce their own code into downloads independently of project maintainers? Does Github have oversight to monitor projects and ensure that a project itself has not been compromised by its official maintainers acting maliciously? Does it have a history of past use for such malicious purposes, and if so, how did it respond?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with anything you download over the internet, there could be malicious stuff when you download anything, some antivirus quickscan keep novices happy, most do automatically nowadays as people use the files.

When you do compile it and run it, well, it is assumed you KNOW what the program is when you compile you will have all the source code for it to compile.  If the program is communicating with the internet through a backdoor, the backdoor should be pretty elaborate and is often not some simple 1 line of code (If the program is using any 3rd party linked libraries, checkout the libraries themselves).....security concern can go on and on.

but in the end, **if you trust the dev who are working on the tree, download and run it.** GitHub has pretty secure end-to-end transmission, and you can check the integrity of the repo with checksums to virtually eliminate the man-in-the-middle stuff.

Comment: thanks for the solid advice Andrew. When in doubt, read and understand the code!

Comment: While I mostly agree, the paranoid side of me would point out that if Github's infrastructure were compromised to where a download could be altered, the checksums could just as easily be altered. Checksums are only useful if they're downloaded from a trusted source. So they can reduce risk if you download the checksum from a different source, or have a checksum that was downloaded at a prior date and then you later download an archive to compare them to, but downloading them together from the same source at the same time has little benefit other than preventing a corrupted download.

Answer (score 15):

Nothing that you download from the internet is 100% safe. However, you can generally gauge the safety of code on Github by the following factors:

- **# of Contributors/Commits:** This tells you that there are a lot of people working on it, not just a single bad actor. While it is possible that it is a group conspiracy to infect users' computers, a larger # of people working to improve the code is generally a good sign.
- **# of Stars:** Basically shows how many people are interested in the project. You can take this as a crowd-verified reputation system of sorts. If a lot of people are interested, it is likely not malicious.
- **Activity:** Are people updating it, fixing bugs, etc? Ensure that there aren't open unaddressed bugs.

In terms of quality, you should also look for good documentation and the existence of unit tests to check that the code is clean.

Comment: Thanks wraasch! That is helpful. I just wasn't sure what to look for before downloading any programs on my computer.