# What are the steps to validate Code available from GitHub (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, security

I would like to know what are the steps that you take to check whether code in GitHub is safe. I am learning flutter and would like to copy some projects from GitHub to dismantle them and learn about each component. The project under question is here: https://github.com/sanogotech/flutter_pet_finder

But as always, content on GitHub might not be safe, so how can I validate that this is safe? I know one aspect is to know each piece and the purpose of that piece. But for me that is a bit tricky at least now. What are your steps to validate a piece of code is safe?

If someone could provide an example on the given project https://github.com/sanogotech/flutter_pet_finder that would even be more than perfect!

I highly appreciate and apologies for asking such a simple question.

Answer (score 1):

Like many other sites and servers, there are both secure and insecure, and there is no 100% guarantee on any service or site.
To see who is using the project?
How active is the project?
What errors or requests did it have?

You should check these and review as much as possible to copy and clone

This type can also be useful for you

[if you trust the dev who are working on the tree, download and run it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46382393/8577321)

[How safe is it to host sensitive data on repository sites like github, bitbucket, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926744/how-safe-is-it-to-host-sensitive-data-on-repository-sites-like-github-bitbucket)

[How secure would github hosting be for private repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989837/how-secure-would-github-hosting-be-for-private-repositories)

Comment: I went through the project I outlined in the upper section and could detect nothing. I would assume mostly one would need to look for external connections, some odd files being triggered? Or am I wrong?

Comment: The project you mentioned above is a fork version of an original project, I suggest you review the original version and you can even Creating an issue .

Comment: https://github.com/gerfagerfa/pet_finder , this is main repository of what you want .